How to read nextjs server action function name and parameters in middleware (app router)
When server actions are called, they manifest as a POST request from the user's current route. I'm trying to get information about the function name and params in middleware
export default async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  console.log('request', request)
}

When I inspect request, I find no references to the function name or the params passed, but i'm only crudely inspecting and haven't ruled out serialization.
In short, how can I see a server action's function name and params in middleware? I definitely can see the server action requests come through, and their associated method/route..but I'm not seeing any details on the function name and params themselves. Any help greatly appreciated!

Middleware runs before the function, so there is no function info for the function after called, that internal handled by next.ns

next js hash server action name and passing it to server from header, params are accessible from request.json(), try this export default async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {   const actionHashNamed = request.headers.get("Next-Action");   if (actionHashNamed) console.log(actionHashNamed, await request.json()); } i dont know what params it use to make the hash but function name, file name, directory can change function hash name.


Here's what I could gather from reading some of Next.js' sources (v14.2.5) and articles online:
TL;DR - The answer is quite far below, please scroll down.
Citing from this site:

This means that it isn’t just a function call: there is actually an HTTP request made to the API to call the function. You can see it in the Network tab of your DevTools:
The endpoint is at the same path as your current page but:

Uses the POST method,
Needs some headers, such as the Next-Action one, containing some kind of ID for the server action,
Gets the parameters to pass to the function from the request body (as JSON).

When you copy the server action ID from the headers, you can even call the API endpoint using cURL:
$ curl 'http://localhost:3001/getting-info-from-server' \
  -H 'Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8' \
  -H 'Next-Action: da9f55acc16563503a57a4fdfe567f8770898818' \
  -X POST --data-raw '["World"]'
0:["$@1",["development",null]]
1:"Hello World!"


It appears that Next.js Server Actions are done by calling the same endpoint where the page is rendered, but as a POST request with a rather intriguing Next-Action header.
As I scour more about this Next-Action header, it's actually the identifier of a Server action. When you try to change it to something else, Next.js will fallback to responding the entire page as usual.
I made a simple server action adder with next, and here's me re-playing the same server action request, and it works as expected:

But when I tried changing the Next-Action header, Next.js just returns the entire page instead:

And I also see this error from the console:
server action with id aaaaaaaaaaa46aa8af80688ae3c3cc0d1226193a
Error: Failed to find Server Action "aaaaaaaaaaa46aa8af80688ae3c3cc0d1226193a". This request might be from an older or newer deployment. Original error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'workers')


Okay, so Next-Action is the ID of a server action function that's defined in that page. But how does Next.js translate that Next-Action to know which functions to be called?
Well, the answer is that Next.js preprocesses your code before it's actually run. The server action functions I wrote went through a build process that Next.js custom-tailored to transform my code to interface with Next.js internal APIs.
The cool thing is that it interfaces with SWC and uses rust for the transformation.
Here's the file that's responsible to transform server actions.
There are a bunch of cases that the transformer will need to handle, like "use server"-ed actions.ts file, functions inside client components, and probably a lot more that I don't know.
Interestingly, on each and every cases the code found a legible server action function, it calls the function generate_action_id to generate an ID for the server action, sounds familiar?
And as we could see in the code, this is the function that generates the server action ids we see in Next-Action!:
// located at
// next.js/packages/next-swc/crates/next-custom-transforms/src/transforms/server_actions.rs
// line 1231-1241
fn generate_action_id(file_name: &str, export_name: &str) -> String {
    // Attach a checksum to the action using sha1:
    // $$id = sha1('file_name' + ':' + 'export_name');
    let mut hasher = Sha1::new();
    hasher.update(file_name.as_bytes());
    hasher.update(b":");
    hasher.update(export_name.as_bytes());
    let result = hasher.finalize();

    hex_encode(result)
}

The hash is made by sha1-hashing ${filename}:${exportname}.
I actually tried to hash any possible combination of filename or pathname with the export name, but I couldn't get to reproduce the same hash Next.js' .
But what does it look like after being transformed? Well, I couldn't exactly pinpoint exactly where Next.js' custom SWC integration outputs its files. But here's what I could find on the .next folder: Lo, and behold!


The file is .next/server/app/page.js

There's a lot going on within this file. The actual file is minified and wrapped with eval() statements, so I did some work making it a bit nicer to be read.
The main takeaway here is that the function seems to be exposed by its action ID, not by name or anything. So, what I could conclude is that Next.js references the server action function by its action id.

Let's take another trip to how does Next.js receive a request, determine whether it's a server action or not, searching for the actual server action function, to finally executing the function!
In short, when a request comes into an app-rendered page, it gets processed by this function: (the original function is huge, I'm only showing the parts that might be of interest)
async function renderToHTMLOrFlightImpl(...) {
  // ...

  const isActionRequest = getServerActionRequestMetadata(req).isServerAction

  // ...

  if (isStaticGeneration) { ... }
  else {
    // ...
    if (isActionRequest) {
      // For action requests, we handle them differently with a special render result.
      const actionRequestResult = await handleAction({ ... })
      // ...
    }
    // ...
  }
}

The line below determines whether the request is a server action or not in the line:
const isActionRequest = getServerActionRequestMetadata(req).isServerAction

Which links to this function:
export function getServerActionRequestMetadata(
  req: IncomingMessage | BaseNextRequest | NextRequest
): { ... } {
  let actionId: string | null
  let contentType: string | null

  if (req.headers instanceof Headers) {
    actionId = req.headers.get(ACTION_HEADER.toLowerCase()) ?? null
    contentType = req.headers.get('content-type')
  } else {
    actionId = (req.headers[ACTION_HEADER.toLowerCase()] as string) ?? null
    contentType = req.headers['content-type'] ?? null
  }

  const isURLEncodedAction = Boolean(
    req.method === 'POST' && contentType === 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  )
  const isMultipartAction = Boolean(
    req.method === 'POST' && contentType?.startsWith('multipart/form-data')
  )
  const isFetchAction = Boolean(
    actionId !== undefined &&
      typeof actionId === 'string' &&
      req.method === 'POST'
  )

  const isServerAction = Boolean(
    isFetchAction || isURLEncodedAction || isMultipartAction
  )

  return {
    // ...
    isServerAction,
  }
}

Which returns a true isServerAction if actionId exists, and the method is POST. And hey! that actionId is actually the content of the Next-Action header that we previously saw.
Next up, when a request is thought to be a server action, it will be further processed by the function handleAction:
const actionRequestResult = await handleAction({ ... })

Let's see how does that function work: (which is also way too huge, I'm only going to show some important parts)
try {
  actionModId =
    actionModId ?? getActionModIdOrError(actionId, serverModuleMap)
} catch (err) {
  if (actionId !== null) {
    console.error(err)
  }
  return {
    type: 'not-found',
  }
}

// ...

const actionHandler = (
  await ComponentMod.__next_app__.require(actionModId)
)[
// `actionId` must exist if we got here, as otherwise we would have thrown an error above
  actionId!
]

const returnVal = await actionHandler.apply(null, bound)

On the try catch statement, the code attempts to find the associated actionModId (which I presume is the module id), as seen from the function definition:
function getActionModIdOrError(
  actionId: string | null,
  serverModuleMap: ServerModuleMap
): string {
  try {
    // if we're missing the action ID header, we can't do any further processing
    if (!actionId) {
      throw new Error("Invariant: Missing 'next-action' header.")
    }

    const actionModId = serverModuleMap?.[actionId]?.id

    if (!actionModId) {
      throw new Error(
        "Invariant: Couldn't find action module ID from module map."
      )
    }

    return actionModId
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(
      `Failed to find Server Action "${actionId}". This request might be from an older or newer deployment. ${
        err instanceof Error ? `Original error: ${err.message}` : ''
      }`
    )
  }
}

Recall that we encountered the Failed to find Server Action "${actionId}". This request might be from an older or newer deployment error as I tried changing the Next-Action header to something else. It failed to find the module that nests the actual server action function, so it threw that exception! Cool!
And as we move on to the next few lines, the code finally loads the actual module, retrieves the function from it, and calling it with .apply:
const actionHandler = (
  await ComponentMod.__next_app__.require(actionModId)
)[
// `actionId` must exist if we got here, as otherwise we would have thrown an error above
  actionId!
]

const returnVal = await actionHandler.apply(null, bound)

There it is! The actionHandler.apply(null, bound) invocation dove into the SWC-transformed and webpack-minified code that we once wrote, doing the action that we wanted to do.
The Answer
So.. what did we get from this journey?
The fact is that Next.js makes use of the actionId value (which is the Next-Action header) until the end to find and execute a server action that we wrote.
So, with a sad tone, it's not possible to determine what the function name of a server action request only by relying on the req Request object from the middleware. (but I figured out a workaround, scroll down a bit)
You can know whether a POST request is a Server Action request by checking whether it contains the Next-Action header, but that's as far as you could go.
You probably could, however, have an object that maps to each functions by their action IDs. As such:
const serverActions: Record<string, Record<string, { name: string }>> = {
  '/': {
    "88e850d9d0846aa8af80688ae3c3cc0d1226193a": {
      name: "mathAdd",
    },
    // ...
  },
  // ...
}

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  console.log(`[middleware] ${request.method} at ${request.nextUrl.pathname}`);

  if (request.method === "POST" && request.headers.has("Next-Action")) {
    const actions = serverActions[request.nextUrl.pathname];
    const action = actions?.[request.headers.get("Next-Action")!];

    if (action) {
      console.log(`[middleware] server action \`${action.name}\` is called.`);
      console.log(`[middleware] parameters: ${await request.text()}`);
    }
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
}

But this approach is:

Way too hacky.
Error-prone.
Has the possibility of breaking in the next updates of Next.js.

A Workaround
As I was about to submit this answer, an idea suddenly popped out of my head. Okay, since you can determine whether it's a server function or not, and you could read the parameters in the response as json in the form of array, you could just put a literal string as parameter!
Here's what the server action function would look like:
export async function mathAdd(_: "mathAdd", a: number, b: number) {
  return a + b;
}

Here's how you call it:
<button
  onClick={async () => {
    const result = await mathAdd("mathAdd", a: number, b: number);
    // ...
  }}
>Add</button>

And in the middleware, we could just get the 0th value of the parameter. How convenient!
if (request.method === "POST" && request.headers.has("Next-Action")) {
  const parameters = await request.json();
  if (!Array.isArray(parameters))
    return new NextResponse(null, { status: 400 });

  console.log(`[middleware] server action \`${parameters[0]}\` is called.`);
  console.log(`[middleware] parameters: ${parameters}`);
}

But this does have some security implications. There could be a malicious actor that changed the 0th parameter to be something else. You might need to watch out for that.

This has gotten way too deep that I had imagined, but this was really fun! Thank you for your question, I too now understand a lot about Next.js' internals! :)
Please correct me if you found anything erroneous about my answer! Thank you!

this is not scalable, thanks for the suggestion tho.
